# Remove All html tag except one tag by BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I need to extract all the text and `<a>` tags from a page but I dont know how to do it.
Here is what I have so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def cleanMe(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html) # create a new bs4 object from the html data loaded
    for script in soup(["script", "style"]): # remove all javascript and stylesheet code
    script.decompose()
    # get text
    text = soup.get_text()
    # break into lines and remove leading and trailing space on each
    lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
    # break multi-headlines into a line each
    chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
    # drop blank lines
    text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)
    return text

testhtml = "<!DOCTYPE HTML>\n<head>\n<title>THIS IS AN EXAMPLE </title><style>.call {font-family:Arial;}</style><script>getit</script><body>I need this text with this <a href="http://example.com/">link</a> captured.</body>"
cleaned = cleanMe(testhtml)
print (cleaned)
```

**Output:**

```
THIS IS AN EXAMPLE I need this text with this link captured.
```

**My desired output**:

```
THIS IS AN EXAMPLE I need this text with this <a href="http://example.com/">link</a> captured.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the below:-

```
def cleanMe(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser') # create a new bs4 object from the html data loaded
    for script in soup(["script", "style"]): # remove all javascript and stylesheet code
        script.decompose()
    # get text
    text = soup.get_text()
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        if 'href' in link.attrs:
            repl=link.get_text()
            href=link.attrs['href']
            link.clear()
            link.attrs={}
            link.attrs['href']=href
            link.append(repl)
            text=re.sub(repl+'(?!= *?</a>)',str(link),text,count=1)

    # break into lines and remove leading and trailing space on each
    lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
    # break multi-headlines into a line each
    chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
    # drop blank lines
    text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)
    return text
```

What we've done new is below

```
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        text=re.sub(link.get_text()+'(?!= *?</a>)',str(link),text,count=1)
```

For each set of anchor tags replace once the text in the anchor(`link`) with the whole anchor itself. Note that we make replacement only once on the first appearing `link` text.

The regex `link.get_text()+'(?!= *?</a>)'` makes sure that we only replace the `link` text only if it was not replaced already.

`(?!= *?</a>)`  is a negative lookahead which avoids any `link` that does not occur with a `</a>` appended.

But this is not the most fool proof way. Most fool proof way is to go through each tag and get the text out.

See the working code [here](https://repl.it/MLjy/2)

Comment: Thanks for quick an explained answer. There is just a minor problem. I need to remove all other nested tags and attributes within `<a>` tags except `href`. How can I do it?

Comment: updated the answer with your requirement. See updated now you need to check `if 'href' in link.attrs:` before you include the `<a>` tags.

Comment: This is one my my output:
`<a href="https://example.com" style="border-style:none !important;outline-style:none !important;color:inherit!important;" target="blank"> <p class="content" style="Margin:0 !important;font-size:18px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;padding-top:0;text-align:center;"> LINK </p></a>`

but I need simple form:
`<a href="https://example.com"> LINK </a>`

Comment: Your update didn't change output. I guess using `link.attrs['href']` solve the problem but I don't now how!

Comment: In one case `<p>` under `<a>` is printed but in the other it is cleaned up.

Comment: @MehdiRahimi was the demo satisfactory?

Comment: please run your code by this input: `<a href="https://example.com" style="border-style:none !important;outline-style:none !important;color:inherit!important;" target="blank"> <p class="content" style="Margin:0 !important;font-size:18px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;paddi‌​ng-top:0;text-align:‌​center;"> LINK </p></a>`

I did it by your demo but attrs `style` and `target` still appear.

Comment: ah got your  point now... I did not realise there were other attributes that you wanted cleaned. I thought only <p>

Comment: This answer is exactly what I was looking for. But **I'm new** to stackoverflow and have not earned the appropriate voting privilege to accept or vote on answer! So what should I do now?

Answer (score 8):

Consider using another library besides BeautifulSoup. I use this:

```
from bleach import clean

def strip_html(self, src, allowed=['a']):
    return clean(src, tags=allowed, strip=True, strip_comments=True)
```